# I can't test the visibility of elements rendered in my backbone view

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, jasmine, sinon

I'm working on a Backbone.js application and while adding tests with [Jasmine & Sinon](http://tinnedfruit.com/2011/04/26/testing-backbone-apps-with-jasmine-sinon-3.html) I had problems to determine the visibility of some DOM elements: some of them where detected as not visible in the tests while I could see them correctly in my application.

I created a small example that replicates the problem, the same test is run twice on two sets of elements:

- the first set is present directly in SpecRunner.html
- the second one has been rendered as a Backbone view

The test itself is using `jQuery.is(':visible')` (via jasmine-jquery's `.toBeVisible()`) to know if elements are visible or not. It passes for the first set, not for the second one.

I shared the code here as a github project : https://github.com/maximevaly/3789_js

I guess I forgot something, or maybe misused a library, but I can't put my finger on it so if you have any clue... :)

Thanks!
Maxime

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is that your `StuffView.el` is not attached to DOM, hence is always not visible. You probably misunderstand `className` and `tagName` parameters: they aren't used as selectors, but to construct a brand new element.

This fixes the second test.

```
el : "div.container",
//tagName : 'div',
//className : 'container',
```

Alternatively you can attach the view to DOM manually in the test

```
$("body").append(this.view.el);
```